# loop push to a new array the numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the below code that is not working.

```
    var array = [1, 3, 2]
    var newArray = []

  getNewArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < array[i]; x++) {
        this.newArray.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.newArray);
  }
```

What i would like to achieve is to use the numbers in a array to loop through the number of times. with the results as shown below

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
   0:
     count:(1) [1]
   1:
     count:(3) [1,2,3]
   2:
     count:(2) [1,2]
```

Right now it is displaying as

```
(4) [1, 2, 2, 1]
  0: 1
  1: 2
  2: 2
  3: 1
```

Comment: Your inputs are objects and not arrays! so they are missing most of the array functions.

Comment: sorry, should have type properly, i know [ ] is array. haha. have edited it

Comment: @Devora What you want to store in result array? Items from existing array or value of x.

Comment: @Devora check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2]
var newArray = []

function getNewArray() {
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 var tmp = [];
 for (let x = 0; x < array[i]; x++) {
  tmp.push(x+1);
 }
 this.newArray.push(tmp);

}
}
getNewArray();
console.log(this.newArray);
```

Comment: sorry, i just type it out, thought those declaring and syntax shouldnt be a concern. What i need help is with the algo.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ES6 features, you can try a combination of `.map` + `Array.from`.

#### Idea:

- Use `Array.map` and loop over every item.
- Use this item as length and create a new array using `Array.from`.
- Pass a `mapper` function to populate array.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2];
var result = array.map((item) => Array.from({
  length: item
}, (_, i) => i + 1));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2];
var newArray = [];

function getNewArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var tempArray = [];
      for (let x = 0; x < array[i]; x++) {
        tempArray.push(array[i]);
      }
      newArray.push(tempArray);
    }
    console.log(this.newArray);
}

getNewArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

With some array magic

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2]
var newArray = []

let getNewArray = () => {
  newArray = array.map( x => Array(x).fill().map( (_,i) => i+1 ) )
  console.log(newArray);
}
getNewArray()
```

Comment: Added function call so we can see output when we run snippet. If not required, kindly revert it.